# Split text into numbers or decimal numbers and strings in java

Tags: java, regex, string

So I have an array of strings and I want to split the words to numbers (or decimal numbers) and keep the characters and put them into an array. I am using a positive lookahead to keep the other characters. So "600g" should be split into {"600", "g"}, "bacon" shouldn't be split: {"bacon"} and "1,54g" should be split into {"1,54", "g"}

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Words = {"bacon", "1,54g", "eggs", "600g", "jalapeno.300g"};
            for (int i = 0; i < Words.length; i++) {
                String[] SplitWord = Words[i].split("(?=\\d+[.,]\\d+|\\d+)");
                System.out.println(Words[i]);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SplitWord));
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
bacon
[bacon]
1,54g
[1,, 5, 4g]
eggs
[eggs]
600
[6, 0, 0]
jalapeno.300g
[jalapeno., 3, 0, 0g]
```

I believe the regex is faulty, but couldn't get other regexes to work.

```
"[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+|[0-9]+"
```

Comment: You should be putting your regex in as a match group to get 300.. i.e. use (<regex>). Use regex101 to test regex vs string until you get desired result, then generate Java from it.

Comment: Maybe easier to *match* e.g. [`[\d,]+|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/wbNN1G/1) (see *code generator*) - be aware that your `(?=\d+[.,]\d+|\d+)` just looks if there is a digit ahead, same like `(?=\d)`

Comment: Perhaps splitting like `(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[^\d\s][.,])(?=\d)` https://regex101.com/r/Lj1Jsf/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the pattern to split on more specific by asserting what should or should not be on the left and the right of the current position.

```
(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[^\d\s][.,])(?=\d)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])` Assert a digit to the left, and a-zA-Z to the right
- `|` Or
- `(?<=[^\d\s][.,])(?=\d)` Assert a char other than a digit or whitespace char followed by either `.` or `,` to the left and a digit to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5pCPJH/1).

Or taking `g` or `kg` into account in the first lookahead:

```
(?i)(?<=\d)(?=k?g\b)|(?<=[^\d\s][.,])(?=\d)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQP4OR/1).

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Words = {"bacon", "1,54g", "eggs", "600g", "jalapeno.300g"};
        for (String word : Words) {
            String[] SplitWord = word.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[^\\d\\s][.,])(?=\\d)");
            System.out.println(word);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SplitWord));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
bacon
[bacon]
1,54g
[1,54, g]
eggs
[eggs]
600g
[600, g]
jalapeno.300g
[jalapeno., 300, g]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

- `(?i)` - ignore case
- `(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z.])` - preceded by digit and followed by letter or .
- `(?<=[a-z.])(?=\\d)` - preceded by letter or . and followed by digit

```
String[] words = {"bacon", "1,54g", "eggs", "600g", "jalapeno.300g"};
String pat = "(?i)(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z.])|(?<=[a-z.])(?=\\d)";
for (String w : words) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(w.split(pat)));
}
```

prints

```
[bacon]
[1,54, g]
[eggs]
[600, g]
[jalapeno., 300, g]
```